# How to change the active class when clicking on other link using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

When I click on the "li" with no class="active", i want jquery to add a class on the empty `<li>` and remove it from the other "li"

I have the following code:

```js
$("li").click(function() {
  // If this isn't already active
  if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
    // Remove the class from anything that is active
    $("li.active").removeClass("active");
    // And make this active
    $(this).addClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="navbar2" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active" style="font-family:Merriweather;"><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menu" style="font-family:Merriweather;"><a href="advertize.aspx">Advertise</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown" style="font-family:Merriweather;">
          <a href="exhibition.aspx" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Exhibitions <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li style="font-family:Merriweather;"><a href="dubaiexhibitions.aspx">Trade fairs in U.A.E</a></li>
            <li style="font-family:Merriweather;"><a href="exhibition.aspx">Trade fairs worldwide</a></li>
            <li style="font-family:Merriweather;"><a href="addexhibition.aspx">Add Your Event</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li style="font-family:Merriweather;"><a href="subscribe.aspx">Subscribe</a></li>
        <li style="font-family:Merriweather;"><a href="member_benefits.aspx">Memberships</a></li>
        <li style="font-family:Merriweather;"><a href="aboutus.aspx">About us</a></li>
        <li style="font-family:Merriweather;"><a href="news.aspx">News</a></li>
        <li style="font-family:Merriweather;"><a href="contactus.aspx">Contact us</a></li>
        <li style="font-family:Merriweather;"><a href="media_partners.aspx">Partners</a></li>
        <li style="font-family:Merriweather;"><a href="login.aspx"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>


      </ul>
      <a href="addlisting.aspx" target="_blank" class="floatingbanner"></a>
    </div>

    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

I tried the above code but it didn't work.

Comment: I converted your code to a snippet and added CSS for `active` class. See it yourself; it works fine. The problem, which I see is that when you click on a link, the browser tries to navigate to it, in which case, you won't see any change the menu.

Comment: @31piy i tried adding css but still it is not working....  alpha.dubaiexporters.com

Comment: @chetankambli Your code is working, check browser console for errors maybe there is an issue, and if there are any errors added it to your question

Answer (score 1):

As commented bellow, your code seems to works fine. But I suggest you to simplify the code for more efficient.
If your goal is clicked `<li>` must become `<li class="active">` and then remove `class="active"` from other `<li>` elements, then you don't have to check whether it is currently active or not. You can simply do this:

```
$("li").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```